# PHP SoapClient error

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to get some information using a soap call but I'm getting the following warnings/errors:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(https://ec2amaz-dbmdpji/ExtServices/contract/ContractService.svc?xsd=xsd0): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://ec2amaz-dbmdpji/ExtServices/contract/ContractService.svc?xsd=xsd0"

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://ec2amaz-dbmdpji/ExtServices/contract/ContractService.svc?xsd=xsd0'

Here's my call:

```
$client = new SoapClient(SAAM_URL, array(
            'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT, 
            'use' => SOAP_LITERAL));
```

Where SAAM_URL is a constant with the URL (is a https:// url).

Somebody told me that the issue might be related to a problem with the ssl certificate, so I tried to 'cancel' the verification by doing:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                            'allow_self_signed' => true
                            )
                    ));

$client = new SoapClient(SAAM_URL, array(
            'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT, 
            'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
            'stream_context' => $context));
```

but nothing happened, I'm still getting the same errors. Any suggestions?

PD: I checked the url and it's displaying the right content.

Thanks

Comment: Bad URL or Local DNS Issue. Are you able to resolve the IP from the hostname at the command prompt at all?

Comment: Unless you have defined `ec2amaz-dbmdpji` in your hosts file, that is not a valid domain name. It looks like it was intended to be some Amazon EC2 platform host.

Comment: I tried: wget url_used and it connects but throws and error saying that it cannot verify the certificate. How can I connect insecurely?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski why ec2amaz-dbmdpji is being displayed? it isn't even part of the URL (SAAM_URL). I don't think I have access to the host file, is there a way around it?

Comment: @johansebasb What _is_ defined in the constant `SAAM_URL`?  Post `var_dump(constant('SAAM_URL'))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same trouble, then I used SoapUI then I found out that the wsdl is redirecting to the other address.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not use your stream context for accessing the `WSDL` file.  The stream context is only used for the actual `SOAP` call.

This presents a problem, but one option is to download the `WSDL` and the schemas it includes, and use them locally.

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359781/php-soap-ssl-how-to-trust-self-signed-certificate) that has a similar problem, with a possible workaround.