# PHP Soap ssl how to trust self-signed certificate

Tags: php, web-services, ssl, soap, wsdl

I am making a client in php with soap for a webservice in .net.
The webservice run over https with a self-signed certificate and for the tests I must trust this certificate without install it.

The problem is that I allways get this error:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl".

Here is my code:

```
$opts = [
        'ssl' => [
            // set some SSL/TLS specific options
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        ],
         'http'=>[
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        ]
    ];

    // Initialize Soap Client
    $this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array('ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,  'location' => 'https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc','stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts), 'exceptions' => true, 'trace' => true));
```

I was able to get the wsdl with wget:

wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3  https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl --no-check-certificate

Hope someone can help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PHP ignores your stream context when downloading the `WSDL` file.  A workaround is to download the `WSDL` file, and all the schema imports to your local file system (I'm using `tidy` here to pretty print the XML):

```
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?wsdl --no-check-certificate -O - | tidy -xml -indent > PSAService.svc?wsdl
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd0 --no-check-certificate -O - | tidy -xml -indent > PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd0
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd1 --no-check-certificate -O - | tidy -xml -indent > PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd1
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd2 --no-check-certificate -O - | tidy -xml -indent > PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd2
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd3 --no-check-certificate -O - | tidy -xml -indent > PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd3
```

Next, you have to edit `PSAService.svc?wsdl` (the filename that wget saved to) and change the imports to point to your local system instead of the web.  Use the **replace-all** feature in your favorite editor and replace `'https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/'` with `''`:

**Example**
**Before:**

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd0"
  namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd1"
  namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd2"
  namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSA.Service.MessageObjects.Pregunta" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd3"
  namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSA.Service.MessageObjects.Respuesta" />
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

**After:**

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd0"
  namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd1"
  namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd2"
  namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSA.Service.MessageObjects.Pregunta" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="PSAService.svc?xsd=xsd3"
  namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PSA.Service.MessageObjects.Respuesta" />
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Repeat for each of the files that were downloaded.

Next, change your code to the following (I assume here that all PHP/WSDL files are in the same folder):

```
$opts = [
'ssl' => [
  // set some SSL/TLS specific options
  'verify_peer' => false,
  'verify_peer_name' => false,
  'allow_self_signed' => true
],
  'http'=>[
    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
  ]
];

// Initialize Soap Client
$client = new SoapClient('PSAService.svc?wsdl', array('ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,  'location' => 'https://winsystemsintl.com:54904/PSAService.svc','stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts), 'exceptions' => true, 'trace' => true));
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Now the `SoapClient` has skipped downloading the `WSDL` from the web, and you're ready to start making calls using your stream context.

Comment: Yes that is true, I definitely would not do this in a production environment, but it useful for testing purposes if a developer needs to use a self-signed cert.

Comment: Whoops I can't edit my previous comment, this is the comment complete: Hi Kris, thank you very much for your answer, but now I get this error `Could not connect to host'. I think that it could be a problem with the webservice certificate, so I spoke with them and they will gave me test credentials for the production webservice to test it, yes I could connect to production webservice without any problem... Again thanks a lot.